# Querying for a value out of a json field Postgres

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, jsonb

I have the following column in my database which is a postres jsonb object. I am just trying to fetch the value of additional_data from mytable which has the json string in it.

```
select additional_data from mytable;
```

```json
{"latitude":"123", "longitude":"234"}
{"latitude":"567", "longitude":"890"}
```

i'm just trying to get the value of latitude for my query and I am unable to figure out how the exact syntax would need to be for this. I tried to do the following

```
select latitude->>'additional_data' from mytable;
select latitude->'additional_data' from mytable;
select latitude#>>'additional_data' from mytable;
```

but when I do this, I get the following error

```
SQL Error [42703]: ERROR: column "latitude" does not exist
Position: 8
```

but that column definitely exists. Not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: I think your fields are reversed -- try `SELECT additional_data->>'latitude' FROM mytable;`

Comment: That works. If you can write the same as an answer, I will accept it as the solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [PostgreSQL documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html), you will need to reference the column on the left side of the operator, and the JSON key on the right side of the operator:

```
select additional_data->>'latitude' from mytable;
select additional_data->'latitude' from mytable;
select additional_data#>>'latitude' from mytable;
```